# Count occurences for each year in pandas dataframe based on subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Imagine a `pandas`dataframe that are given by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'location': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    'date': [pd.to_datetime('01-01-{}'.format(year)) for year in [2015, 2016, 2015, 2017, 2018]]
}).set_index('id')
```

which looks like this

```
    location       date
id                     
1          1 2015-01-01
1          2 2016-01-01
1          3 2015-01-01
2          1 2017-01-01
2          2 2018-01-01
```

Now I want to create a column for each year represented in the `date`column that counts occurences by `id`. Hence the resulting data frame should be like this

```
    location       date  2015  2016  2017  2018
id                                             
1          1 2015-01-01     2     1     0     0
1          2 2016-01-01     2     1     0     0
1          3 2015-01-01     2     1     0     0
2          1 2017-01-01     0     0     1     1
2          2 2018-01-01     0     0     1     1
```

Now I imagine using [`pd.groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/groupby.html) but I can't figure out the best solution.

---

My own solution was

```
df['year'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.year)
df = pd.merge(
    df, 
    pd.pivot_table(df, 'date', 'id', 'year', 'count').fillna(0).astype(int), 
    left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('year', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `get_dummies`

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.date.dt.year).sum(level=0))

         date  location  2015  2016  2017  2018
id                                             
1  2015-01-01         1     2     1     0     0
1  2016-01-01         2     2     1     0     0
1  2015-01-01         3     2     1     0     0
2  2017-01-01         1     0     0     1     1
2  2018-01-01         2     0     0     1     1
```

---

#### `factorize`

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.index)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.date.dt.year)
n, m = shape = len(r), len(c)
b = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int64)
np.add.at(b, (i, j), 1)

df.join(pd.DataFrame(b, r, c).rename_axis('id'))

         date  location  2015  2016  2017  2018
id                                             
1  2015-01-01         1     2     1     0     0
1  2016-01-01         2     2     1     0     0
1  2015-01-01         3     2     1     0     0
2  2017-01-01         1     0     0     1     1
2  2018-01-01         2     0     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Create helper `DataFrame` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `df`:

```
df1 = df.join(df.groupby(['id', df['date'].dt.year]).size().unstack(fill_value=0), on='id')
print (df1)
    location       date  2015  2016  2017  2018
id                                             
1          1 2015-01-01     2     1     0     0
1          2 2016-01-01     2     1     0     0
1          3 2015-01-01     2     1     0     0
2          1 2017-01-01     0     0     1     1
2          2 2018-01-01     0     0     1     1
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby(['id', df['date'].dt.year]).size().unstack(fill_value=0))

date  2015  2016  2017  2018
id                          
1        2     1     0     0
2        0     0     1     1
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.join(pd.crosstab(df.index, df['date'].dt.year), on='id')

print (pd.crosstab(df.index, df['date'].dt.year))
date   2015  2016  2017  2018
row_0                        
1         2     1     0     0
2         0     0     1     1
```